# How to change the colour of a subitem in ListView?

Tags: android

I am making a project in which i am getting the wifi networks that are currently available.
The problem is it is dispaying the wifi networks in white colour. May i know how may i change the colour of list

The code that i used is...

```
WifiManager mainWifi;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    String wifis[];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int list;
    ListView list1;
    Button b;
    ProgressDialog p;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        p=new ProgressDialog(this);
        p.setTitle("Searching Wifi Networks");
        p.setMessage("Loading");
        p.show();

        Thread t= new Thread(new updater());
        t.start();

        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
                        WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
                mainWifi.startScan();

            }
        });
        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();


        // Register broadcast receiver
        // Broacast receiver will automatically call when number of wifi
        // connections changed
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mainWifi.startScan();
            }

    public class updater extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
            p.incrementProgressBy(20);
            for(int ii=0;ii<5;ii++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }p.dismiss();
        }
    }

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        // This method call when number of wifi connections changed
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
            wifis = new String[wifiList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {
                wifis[i] = ((wifiList.get(i).SSID).toString());
            }
            //list1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);




            list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , android.R.id.text1, wifis));

            list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     int itemPosition     = position;

                        // ListView Clicked item value
                        String  itemValue    = (String) list1.getItemAtPosition(position);

                         Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Progressshow.class);
                         i.putExtra("Name", itemValue);
                         startActivity(i);
                }


            });

        }
    }




    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can set/change your activity theme to dark version. It will be applied to your listView as well. Alternatively, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Create Your Own Custom Listview so that you can modify as per your requirement, check this

[Custom List View Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Feel Free To ask question if you have any other query

Comment: i made a very small example of list view but in that it is showing list  subitems in black color may i know why it is showing in white colour

Comment: That androidhive tutorial is very powerful, it shows you that your list items are just another simple layout, which you can modify in xml or in getView() of your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can change background color of your listView with

```
list1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

You can also define your custom layout for list item (instead of using standard `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`) and set you color there with :

```
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
```